# Build transition for pageRouteBuilder in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have implemented routing in my flutter app via on-the-fly route generation with

`onPressed:() => Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(
   pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => new Video(),
 )),`

The transition from one page to another however is instant and without the native 'in from left' or 'in from bottom' animation, depending on whether you target iOS or Android. Is there a way to implement the native OS transitions without having to implement the animation from scratch.

I know that you can pass the `transitionBuilder` parameter to the `PageRouteBuilder` to create transitions, but so far I haven't found any information on how to create the necessary transitions or whether premade transitions are available. Any help with the implementation of the native transitions mentioned above would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use `MaterialPageRoute` instead `PageRouteBuilder`. `MaterialPageRoute` implements transitions by default.

Comment: @HemanthRaj Thanks a lot for your help! Do you know how the parameter `builder` of `MaterialPageRoute` would have to be implemented to route to `Video()` ?

Comment: I just answered your question. Implemening a video with MaterialPageRoute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `MaterialPageBuilder` instead of `PageRouteBuilder`.

To play video, you can look into [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chewie).

example:

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';

final playerWidget = new Chewie(
  new VideoPlayerController(
    'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/videos/butterfly.mp4'
  ),
  aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
  autoPlay: true,
  looping: true,
);

 onPressed:() => Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
   pageBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new Container(child: playerWidget);
   },
 )),
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, exactly what I was looking for!